# Bind the Data in Mat-Table in Angular 8 Using Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an array of array data. i need to bind the data angular mat-table. i have bind the array of object data mat-table. but i dont know how to bind the array of array in mat-table.

Below code is my response

```
[
  [
    "lot-slot_id",
    "CountRows",
    "MinMeasureTime",
    "AvgSiteValue",
    "SpecLow",
    "SpecHigh",
    "CountPassSpec",
    "RatioPassVsTotalTests",
    "lot_id"
  ],
  [
    "Q851325-1",
    "216",
    "3-12-2019 12:46:00",
    "13.40395717",
    "0.151",
    "30",
    "215",
    "0.99537037",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "Q851325-2",
    "72",
    "3-12-2019 12:46:00",
    "13.70907867",
    "0.151",
    "30",
    "72",
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  [
    "Q851325-3",
    "72",
    "3-12-2019 12:46:00",
    "13.65184019",
    "0.151",
    "30",
    "72",
    "1",
    "3"
  ]
]
```

In Component.ts

```
ELEMENT_DATA = data;
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

I need Array[0] should be Th column
(i.e)

```
[
    "lot-slot_id",
    "CountRows",
    "MinMeasureTime",
    "AvgSiteValue",
    "SpecLow",
    "SpecHigh",
    "CountPassSpec",
    "RatioPassVsTotalTests",
    "lot_id"
  ]
```

From `Array[1]` - `Array[3]`  should be in td.

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Have you looked at their documentation? They have multiple examples on how to go about this.

Comment: Yes, I saw the multiple examples. but I not able to bind data into mat-table with this type of response. kindly help me solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the component file

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "table-basic-example",
  styleUrls: ["table-basic-example.css"],
  templateUrl: "table-basic-example.html"
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  tblArr = [
    [
      "lot-slot_id",
      "CountRows",
      "MinMeasureTime",
      "AvgSiteValue",
      "SpecLow",
      "SpecHigh",
      "CountPassSpec",
      "RatioPassVsTotalTests",
      "lot_id"
    ],
    [
      "Q851325-1",
      "216",
      "3-12-2019 12:46:00",
      "13.40395717",
      "0.151",
      "30",
      "215",
      "0.99537037",
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "Q851325-2",
      "72",
      "3-12-2019 12:46:00",
      "13.70907867",
      "0.151",
      "30",
      "72",
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    [
      "Q851325-3",
      "72",
      "3-12-2019 12:46:00",
      "13.65184019",
      "0.151",
      "30",
      "72",
      "1",
      "3"
    ]
  ];
  headerArr = this.tblArr.shift();
}
```

and in the template file

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tblArr">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let h of headerArr; let i = index" [matColumnDef]="h">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{h}}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row[i]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="headerArr"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let tblArr; columns: headerArr"></tr>
</table>
```

A live example can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64541405?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html)

NB: Rename Variables accordingly.